# Load more button does not work for category page

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress, categories

I am tying to make an archive page for all of the posts with category "food".  So I made a php file called category-food.php and added my code, however the code wasn't working properly. I had trouble figuring out why until I pasted the code onto another php file, page-food.php. The code ended up working on the page-food. Does anyone have a reason for why this is the case, and how I can get it to work on category-food.php?

*the main issue was that on the category-food.php my ajax load more button would not show up at all. But on page-food.php the ajax load more button showed up and worked perfectly. This is the plugin I am using for that - https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-load-more/

The code...

```php
<?php
get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel-food');

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
    'cat' => 10,
 ));

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    // display #ajax wrapper only if we have posts
    echo '<div id="ajax"><div class="row">';
    $i = 0;
    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
          $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                   if($i % 3 == 0) {
                     echo '</div><div class="row">';
                   }
                ?>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <article <?php post_class(); ?> >
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                    </article>
                </div>

    <?php $i++; }//end while

    echo '</div></div>'; // close the #ajax wrapper after the post list

    if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
        load_more_button();
    }     

} else { // if there are no posts     
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';     
}//end if

get_footer();
?>
```

UPDATED CODE

```php
<?php
get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel-food');

global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
$wp_query->query($wp_query->query_vars); 


$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
    'cat' => 10,
 ));

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    // display #ajax wrapper only if we have posts
    echo '<div id="ajax"><div class="row">';
    $i = 0;
    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
          $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                   if($i % 3 == 0) {
                     echo '</div><div class="row">';
                   }
                ?>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <article <?php post_class(); ?> >
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                    </article>
                </div>

    <?php $i++; }//end while

    echo '</div></div>'; // close the #ajax wrapper after the post list

    if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
        load_more_button();
    }     

} else { // if there are no posts     
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';     
}//end if

get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy load more uses the `global $wp_query` object to detect whether the load-more button should be visible:

```
//class-easy-load-more.php: 552 
global $wp_query;
...
$wp_query->max_num_pages == 1 ? ' ajax-inactive' : ''
```

You set up `'posts_per_page' => 3` but global `$wp_query` uses a default value of 10. So if in the food category there are less then 10 posts then `max_num_pages`is equal to 1 and load-more button would be hidden.

I think on page `page-food.php` `$wp_query->max_num_pages` equals 0 - so the button is visible.

The default value you can change on the Settings->Reading page but it will affect all catalog/archive pages. 
Instead you can change global `$wp_query` on the `category-food.php` page:

```
get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel-food');

global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
$wp_query->query($wp_query->query_vars); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
    'cat' => 10,
 ));
...
```

Comment: Would you mind putting it into my code for me? I'm still not the best at PHP and when I just tried adding it, I think I put it in the wrong spot because I got an error.

Comment: The only thing on the page was my header, and my carousel (which was messed up) I pasted the code I put in above in my question. But I'm pretty sure somehow I just added the code you suggested in the wrong spot.

Comment: looks like you replaced `$the_query = new WP_Query` code with  the new one? Change it back. You need only add new one without modifying old

Comment: I updated the code again. The load more button now appears but when you press it it goes to this url - http://localhost:8888/wordpress/category/food/?paged=2 - and scrolls back to the top and loads the index page?